# Converting a date to numeric in R

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I have data where I have the dates in YYYY-MM-DD format in one column and another column is num.

packages:

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
```

Running `str(my_data)` produces the following:

```
spec_tbl_df [261 x 2] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ date      : Date[1:261], format: "2017-01-01" "2017-01-08" ...
 $ popularity: num [1:261] 100 81 79 75 80 80 71 85 79 81 ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=
  .. cols(
  ..   date = col_date(format = ""),
  ..   popularity = col_double()
  .. )
 - attr(*, "problems")=<externalptr>
```

I would like to do some time series analysis on this. When running the first line of code for this `decomp <- stl(log(my_data), s.window="periodic")`
I keep running into the following error:

```
Error in Math.data.frame(my_data) : 
  non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: date
```

Originally my date format was in MM/DD/YYYY format, so I feel like I'm... barely closer. I'm learning R again, but it's been a while since I took a formal course in it. I did a precursory search here, but could not find anything that I could identify as helpful (I'm just an amateur.)

Comment: What "analysis" are you doing? It's easier to help if you tell us what code generates an error, and the presence of non-base R packages.

Comment: Maybe: my_data$numbers <- as.numeric(gsub(“-“,””,as.character(my_data$date)))   ?

Comment: @r2evans Of course! Edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have a `data.frame` (or `tibble` variant thereof).  That is not yet time aware.  You can do things like

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df) + aes(x=date, y=popularity) + geom_line()
```

to get a basic line plot properly index by date.

You will have to look more closely at package `forecast` and the examples of functions you want to use to predict or model. Packages like `xts` can help you, i.e.

```
library(xts)
x <- xts(df$popularity, order.by=df$date)
plot(x)  # plot xts object
```

besides plotting you get time- and date aware lags and leads and subsetting.  The rest depends more on what you want to do ... which you have not told us much about.

Lastly, if you wanted to convert your dates to numbers (since Jan 1, 1970) a quick `as.numeric(df$date))` will; but using time-aware operations is often better (but has the learning curve you see now...)